# How to translate dynamic content in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a yii2 base application that i would also like to show to users in different language, i have implemented yii2 i18n translation and everything seems working fine, but i used but i used a file base translating method which handles the static content without problem but then i want to translate Admin input which were saved in the database. For example I already entered Team names in the database but need to show the Team names in different language to different users.

```
<?=\Yii::t('app/teams', '{home_team}', [
     'home_team' => $win['home_team'],
]);?>
<?=\Yii::t('app/teams', '{away_team}', [
    'away_team' => $win['away_team'],
]);?>
```

but then i got an error like this

```
@MISSING: app/teams . Milan FOR LANGUAGE zh-CN @  VS  @MISSING: app/teams . Juventus FOR LANGUAGE zh-CN @
```

and in my `app/teams.php` file i have this in there

```
return[

   'Juventus' => '尤文图斯',
   'Milan' => '米兰',
 ];
```

Note the home_team and away team coming from database table Teams which is maintain and updated only by Admin. How can i make this translation in yii2
my config file

```
'i18n' => [
        'translations' => [
            'app*' => [
                'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
                'basePath' => '@common/messages',
                'fileMap' => [
                    'app' => 'app.php',
                    'app/match' => 'match.php',
                    'app/teams' => 'teams.php',
                    'app/error' => 'error.php',
                ],
                'on missingTranslation' => ['common\components\TranslationEventHandler', 'handleMissingTranslation'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

below is a screen shot of the resulting page
[image]

Comment: How did you configured `i18n` component?

Comment: @rob006 here is my i18n configuration `'i18n' => [
   'translations' => [
    'app*' => [
     'class' => 'yii\i18n\PhpMessageSource',
     'basePath' => '@common/messages',
     'fileMap' => [
      'app' => 'app.php',
         'app/match' => 'match.php',
                        'app/teams' => 'teams.php',
      'app/error' => 'error.php',
                    ],
     'on missingTranslation' => ['common\components\TranslationEventHandler', 'handleMissingTranslation'],
                ],
            ],
        ],`

Comment: Did you tried if `Yii::t('app/teams', 'Juventus')` works?

Comment: @ rob006  thanks i figured out the problem, i had to trim off the white spaces around the strings and it works